# How to destroy_all only dependent of a model and not the model itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to destroy all the dependent of a model and not the model itself. can we do that in rails

Comment: so how to do it. please help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes it is possible.
But it depends and the type of association your models have.

For example, in a `has_many` association you can do this `yourModel.theAssociation.destroy_all` or `yourModel.theAssociation.delete_all` (These are not the same, read the docs below to understand the differences)

But before doing so, since your question lacks info on the models and the types of associations. Please guide yourself reading the **Deleting from Associations**
from the rails docs: [Deleting from Associations Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Delete+or+destroy%3F)

Tip: You should share your code so we can see what you're dealing with and why do you want to do such thing.